# AWS Cloudformation - Multiline Parameters

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm very new to cloudformation templates, and I'm trying to create a template to build AWS ECS codepipelines.

The pipelines will need a CodeBuild stage with a fairly complex buildspec.

I would like to be able specify the buildspec for the build project as a template parameter. However when creating the stack from the template, CloudFormation only seems to allow a single line text box for providing the value for the parameters.

Is there some way to tell it that a particular parameter is a "long text" string, to allow it to show a larger multi-line edit box?

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be possible at the moment.

As a workaround, consider uploading your buildspec to S3 and specify S3 ARN as parameter in your CF template.